# What is the Equivalent of Adding -er to a verb to make it "One who does x"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, suffixes, nouns

In English, to make a verb into "someone or something that does x" we add -er to the verb. Examples:

- crush → crusher
- teach → teacher
- run → runner
- spin → spinner

Is there a similar rule or pattern in Japanese?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [_"Is there a general purpose equivalent for the “agent suffix” -er of English?"_](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15748/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some kanji suffixes can be used for this.

Probably the most generic and closest to `-er` is `-者{しゃ}`：

- 医{い}者{しゃ} (doctor, physician)
- 歯{は}医{い}者{しゃ} (dentist)
- 忍{にん}者{じゃ} (ninja)
- 責任者{せきにんしゃ} (person responsible/in charge)
- 関係者{かんけいしゃ} (authorized person, staff)
- 科学者{かがくしゃ} (scientist)
- 通訳者{つうやくしゃ} (interpreter)

[More such words](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Japanese_words_suffixed_with_%E8%80%85) (Wiktionary link)

*NB*: in some compounds `者` is read as `もの`, e.g. 若{わか}者{もの}, 馬鹿{ばか}者{もの}, 愚{おろ}か者{もの}.

Other common suffixes:

-屋{や}　(usually, but not always used for occupations with a [work]shop)

- 八{や}百{お}屋{や} (greengrocer)
- 肉{にく}屋{や} (butcher)
- 床{とこ}屋{や} (barber)
- 大{おお}屋{や} (landlord/landlady)
- 酒屋{さかや} (sake dealer/brewer)
- 質屋{しちや} (pawnbroker)
- 殺{ころ}し屋{や} (professional killer/hitman)

-家{か} can be used for professions usually(but not always) related to creativity:

- 漫画家【まんがか】 (mangaka, manga/comic writer)
- 画家 【がか】 (painter)
- 作家【さっか】 (writer/author)
- 小説家【しょうせつか】 (novelist, fiction writer)
- 作詞家【さくしか】 (lyricist, songwriter)
- 芸術家【げいじゅつか】 (artist (in entertainment industry))
- 評論家【ひょうろんか】 (critic)
- 農家 【のうか】 (farmer/plant grower)
- 実業家【じつぎょうか】 (businessman)

yet another suffix is -手{しゅ}:

- 歌手{かしゅ} - singer
- 選手{せんしゅ} - sportsman
- 運転手{うんてんしゅ} - driver/chauffeur
- 投手{とうしゅ} - baseball pitcher
- 騎手{きしゅ} - horseman/rider

*NB*: this suffix has been repurposed by Niconico Video users to refer to amateur artists posting videos of their performances. They use the same 手 kanji but with the て (kun) reading:

-歌{うた}い手{て} ([*utaite*](http://utaite.wikia.com/wiki/Utaite), amateur singer) from 歌手{かしゅ} (singer)
-踊{おど}り手{て} (*odorite*, amateur dancer) from 踊{おど}る (dance)

in a few rare cases this suffix is also read -て in common words as well (thanks to @EiríkrÚtlendi):

- 買手【かいて】 (buyer/purchaser)
- 選【えら】び手【て】(selector/chooser)
- 使【つか】い手【て】(user of smth.)

Comment: Don't forget 手{て}, as in terms like 買{かい}手{て} (_"buyer"_), 選{えら}び手{て} (_"chooser, selector"_), etc.

Comment: >所説家 (novelist, fiction writer)
Is this another variant of 小説家?

Answer (score 5):

For sino-Japanese nouns that can also be used as verbs (aka suru-verbs), adding 者 will work, as other answers explain.

For native Japanese verbs (aka *yamato kotoba* verbs), using masu-stem alone will often means "<verb> + er":

- のぞき peeper
- 酔っ払い drunkard
- すり pickpocket (from [掏る](http://jisho.org/search/%E6%8E%8F%E3%82%8B))
- 大食い big eater
- 人殺し murderer
- ピアノ弾き piano player
- 魔法使い (lit. "magic user") wizard

However these are nouns which have been fossilized long ago, and coining a new noun using this rule is generally not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of verb + 人/する人.

Your examples could be:

> 潰す人、教える人、走る人、回す人

Although, there can be a specific word for certain cases such as 先生 for 教える人 in the above.

---

Another interesting example borrows from English's ["-er" concept](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1041463510).

People who like the brand しまむら (shimamura) can be called しまラー (shima-er) and in the same way:

シャネル (chanel)  -> シャネラー

安室奈美恵 (Namie Amuro, a singer) -> アムラー

NOTE: None of these are grammatical and are just slang words.

Answer (score 1):

There is no strictly equivalent construct, although 〇〇する[者]{もの} (or 〇〇する人, 〇〇するの) will often serve.

Aside from that, especially when you have two-kanji Sino-japanese △△するcompounds, a related word on the form of △△[者]{しゃ} or △△さん will sometimes exist.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more, but these are two ways I could think of turning verbs to nouns:

Some words are formed by adding 手:
買い手
売り手
貸し手
借り手
聞き手
送り手

Some words are formed by adding 主:
買い主
売り主
飼い主